# How can you convert duplicates across multiple columns to be NA in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a dataset that I want to convert any duplicates across columns to be NA. I've found answers to help with just looking for duplicates in one column, and I've found ways to remove duplicates entirely (e.g., distinct()). Instead, I have this data:

```
library(dpylr)
test <- tibble(job = c(1:6), 
               name = c("j", "j", "j", "c", "c", "c"),
               id = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1))
```

And want this result:

```
library(dpylr)

answer <- tibble(job = c(1:6), 
                 id = c("j", NA, "j", "c", NA, "c"),
                  name = c(1, NA, 2, 1, NA, 5))
```

And I've tried a solution like this using duplicated(), but it fails:

```
#Attempted solution
library(dpylr)
test %>%
  mutate_at(vars(id, name), ~case_when(
    duplicated(id, name) ~ NA,
    TRUE ~ .
  ))
```

I'd prefer to use tidy solutions, but I can be flexible as long as the answer can be piped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could create a `helper` and then identify duplicates and replace them with `NA` in an `ifelse` statement using `across`:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  mutate(helper = paste(id, name)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(name, id), ~ifelse(duplicated(helper), NA, .)), .keep="unused")
```

```
    job name     id
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 j         1
2     2 NA       NA
3     3 j         2
4     4 c         1
5     5 c         5
6     6 NA       NA
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to convert to `NA`, create a column that includes all the columns with `paste` or `unite` and then `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test %>% 
  unite(full_nm, -job, remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(job, full_nm), ~ replace(.x, duplicated(full_nm), NA))) %>%
  select(-full_nm)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
    job name     id
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 j         1
2     2 <NA>     NA
3     3 j         2
4     4 c         1
5     5 c         5
6     6 <NA>     NA
```

---

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but I actually want to retain duplicates. I clarified my answer to reflect that--I have other columns that do not have duplicates, so I just want NAs for the 2 columns that do have duplicates. Distinct drops the others

Comment: @J.Sabree updated the answer

Comment: what is full_nm? With the updated dataset that I loaded, the solution doesn't work. In my actual dataset, I have columns that are not missing or duplicated, so when I join all of them, it doesn't convert any to NA

Comment: @J.Sabree please check now